# Neo4j service won't start with an imported database on Debian

Tags: neo4j, debian

I've been playing around with neo4j recently on my Debian 7.8 install. It's awesome!

Today I imported around 100000 nodes and 150000 relationships using neo4j-import tool. I stopped the neo4j service and copied the imported database to /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db - but now Neo4j service won't start

```
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [4963]... waiting for server to be ready....... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

Which is weird because it doesn't wait 120 seconds to start - 5 at most. The only log that is produced is console.log in /var/log/neo4j

```
2015-07-01 00:10:24.363+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on 120000
2015-07-01 00:10:26.501+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
```

which isn't very useful. When I remove the database, neo4j is able to start. I copied graph.db to my windows installation and it works well, I can search through nodes etc. so perhaps it has something to do with configuration on my Debian? I added a line in  /etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties

```
 org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout=0
```

but this changed nothing, service start still times out after several seconds. Any ideas?

Here's graph.db messages.log - nothing gets appended when I try to start the service

```
2015-07-01 01:58:12.142+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Import starting
2015-07-01 01:58:12.282+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Creating new db @ /var/www/ddl/scripts/./graph.db/neostore
2015-07-01 01:58:13.238+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Missing counts store, rebuilding it.
2015-07-01 01:58:13.607+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: No lucene scan store index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.
2015-07-01 01:58:13.663+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: No lucene scan store index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.
2015-07-01 01:58:13.952+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Rebuilding lucene scan store, this may take a while
2015-07-01 01:58:13.955+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Lucene scan store rebuilt (roughly -1 nodes)
2015-07-01 01:58:30.337+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: IMPORT DONE in 18s 182ms. Imported:
  95941 nodes
  158227 relationships
  369482 properties
2015-07-01 01:58:30.341+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: About to rotate counts store at transaction 1 to [/var/www/ddl/scripts/./graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/var/www/ddl/scripts/./graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
2015-07-01 01:58:30.344+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Successfully rotated counts store at transaction 1 to [/var/www/ddl/scripts/./graph.db/neostore.counts.db.b], from [/var/www/ddl/scripts/./graph.db/neostore.counts.db.a].
```

Comment: belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: neo4j docs suggest asking here http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/community-support.html

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and compare it with [an on topic section on dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Marcin, can you check graph.db/messages.log ? Are both, the neo4j-import and the neo4j-server the same version?

Comment: Hi Michael. I edited my post to add messages.log. There aren't any errors. and nothing gets appended to the log when I try to start the server. Yes, I installed neo4j with apt-get using instructions on neo4j website and I imported the data on that same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that what I needed to do is make sure my permissions are right. 
I fixed it with

```
chown -r Neo4j:adm graph.db
```

and everything seems to work fine now. I think Neo4j should produce some sort of warning if it can't access graph.db. Now it just exits without any log

Comment: Lifesaver!  +1 on better error log messaging int the neo4j consol.log

Comment: Yes, I'll be able to do that in an hour :) And agreed, neo4j rocks but the messages suck, in general. I raised an issue on github so hopefully they will step up their logging game.

Comment: I now run the import tool by doing a sudo as the neo4j user  `sudo -u neo4j neo4j-import ....`